# how to filter specific table column by cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that stores 10k+ lines of data and want to speed up the filtering via `VBA`. I want to filter my table "Data" in column 5 based on the value in another cell, cell E2.

[image: picture]

I tried code below but if I type anyting in E2 it will just hide all rows in the table.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$E$2" Then
 If Range("E2") = "" Then
  Range("E7").AutoFilter
 Else
  Range("E7").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Range("E2")
 End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If you *tried several solutions*, you should be able to show us at least one of those efforts.

Comment: Are you typing the complete value into E2 ? In what column does your table start?

Comment: I would like to have both options available if possible (full and partial value). Table starts in column A and ends in T. New data is being added to the table on daily basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it, I was referring to wrong column (now it also adds filter back again)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Target.Address = "$E$2" Then
   Range("E7").AutoFilter
    If Range("E2") = "" Then
     Range("E7").AutoFilter
     Else
     Range("E7").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Range("E2")
   End If
  End If
End Sub
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXImA.png)

However it only filters exact values and not partial values. I tried to specify Criteria1 with code below, but it only returns 1 value, example: I have 6 records that ends with value 123, but it will only filter out 1 and not all 6. If I manage to fix it I will post another answer.

`Range("E7").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="*" & Range("E2").Value & "*"`